# How to search with a regular expression in Eclipse?

Tags: php, regex, eclipse

How can I use Eclipse to search all files which have this on their first line:

```
<?
```

instead of this:

```
<?php
```

The following isn't working:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your files have any spacing or indentation? That could cause your regex not to work.

Your regex will match this

```
<?
```

But it won't match  any of these because of the spacing.

```
<? 
 <?
    <?
```

If you want a regex that allows for spaces and indents try this

```
^\s*<\?\s*$
```